# React Native Android: screenPhysicalPixels.width is undefined

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I recently upgraded to RN 0.20 and I now have the following exception thrown when I try to load my app:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'screenPhyisicalPixels.width')
<unknown>
index.android.bundle?platform=android& def=true:32950
requireImpl
index.android.bundle?platform=android& def=true:76
_require
index.android.bundle?platform=android& def=true:36
```

Which apparently causes a JS error the following file:

```
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Dimensions.js at line 30
```

For info, I'm **not** using the [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html#content) API in my app.

Any tip on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear of what command did what exactly, but I fixed it after the following steps, thanks to a combination of @mr-brown and @matija-grcic answers:

1. Set `"react-native": "^0.20.0",` in `package.json`
2. Delete `node_modules`
3. Run `react-native upgrade` (updates `android/app/build.gradle` among others)
4. Uninstall app on my phone
5. `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 7):

You need to update the string in **android/app/build.gradle** to

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.+"
}
```

Then just run

```
npm start
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when upgrading my project from `0.19` to `0.20`.

What did it for me, was running `react-native upgrade`.

After that, you'll probably have to reinstall your modules with `npm install`.

edit: and of course rebuild your app after that via `react-native run-android`.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to remove node_modules folder. After that run on root directory

```
watchman watch-del-all
```

Next step is to run

```
npm install
```

Then start packager manually with

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Thats what helped for me. Good luck!